# Copy a PDF Stream to File

Tags: c#, php, filestream, tcpdf, streamwriter

I'm calling a routine in PHP (TCPDF) from C# via WebRequest using StreamReader. The PDF file is returned as a stream and stored in a string (obv). I know the data being returned to the string is actually a PDF file, as I've tested it in PHP. I'm having a hard time writing the string to a file and actually getting a valid PDF in C#. I know it has something to do with the way I'm trying to encode the file, but the several things I've tried have resulted in 'Not today, Padre' (i.e. they didn't work)

Here's the class I'm using to perform the request (thanks to user 'Paramiliar' for the example I'm using/borrowed/stole):

```
    public class httpPostData
    {
        WebRequest request;
        WebResponse response;

        public string senddata(string url, string postdata)
        {

            // create the request to the url passed in the paramaters
            request = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);


            // set the method to POST
            request.Method = "POST";

            // set the content type and the content length
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = postdata.Length;

            // convert the post data into a byte array
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);

            // get the request stream and write the data to it
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            // get the response
            response = request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            // read the response
            string serverresponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

            //Console.WriteLine(serverresponse);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            return serverresponse;
        }
    } // end class httpPostData
```

...and my call to it

```
httpPostData myPost = new httpPostData();    
// postData defined (not shown)
string response = myPost.senddata("http://www.example.com/pdf.php", postData);
```

In case it isn't clear, I'm stuck writing `string response` to a valid .pdf file. I've tried this (Thanks to user Adrian):

```
static public void SaveStreamToFile(string fileFullPath, Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream.Length == 0) return;

        // Create a FileStream object to write a stream to a file
        using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileFullPath, (int)stream.Length))
        {
            // Fill the bytes[] array with the stream data
            byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);

            // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
            fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
        }
    }

..and the call to it:

    string location = "C:\\myLocation\\";

    SaveStreamToFile(location, response);  // <<-- this throws an error b/c 'response' is a string, not a stream. New to C# and having some basic issues with things like this
```

I think I'm close...a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Fernando: While I appreciate the suggestion (and I'll look at WebClient), you don't really answer the question. Also, as you can see from the example I've posted, there is no file being downloaded, only a stream being captured (won't debate the semantics of why, in a technical sense, that may be the same thing). I don't want to create a file on the server-side - I want to download a stream created by a POST request to the PHP script.

Comment: I'm not going to mark this question 'Answered', as I was never able to figure out how to capture the .pdf stream as a string and then write that string to a valid .pdf file. I was trying to eliminate this:

Comment: (oops) eliminate multiple steps (i.e. creating a file on the server, downloading the file from the server, then deleting the file on the server). Seemed like three unnecessary steps. In the end, that's how I handled it, as I was spending too much time on the solution. I WAS surprised at how quickly those three steps were processed (<1 second, including the d/l of a 50k file). Still, an answer would be nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). Use the method [DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx), or the async ones.

Have fun!
Fernando.-

---

Sorry, I haven't read your comments till now.
I guess you have already done this...

But this may help you (just replace urls and paths) (from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx )

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;

// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;

Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);

// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);     

Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);

Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + Application.StartupPath);
```